# How can I deploy OSGi application?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have created OSGi service and Consumer application from [this](http://o7planning.org/en/10135/java-osgi-tutorial-for-beginners) link.

However application is perfectly working from eclipse run configuration as described in link. Now I want to run this application from windows command line.

I created a xx.jar file using **Export** option in eclipse but when I try to run this jar, it says **'no main manifest attribute, in xx.jar'**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked the the OSGi enRoute tutorials? http://enroute.osgi.org/

Comment: No I haven't. I will look into this and will see if I can get my answers.